# ngtable doesn't show properly

Tags: angularjs, pagination, ngtable

I have downloaded the zip of this `plunkr (http://plnkr.co/edit/ISa4xg?p=preview)` on my computer. When I run the example the table shows but css style is not applied (for example, pagination is in an ugly way). Anyone knows why do I have this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

just simple example to show data into table

// Try like this ............

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th data-ng-click="doSort('name')">Name</th>
                    <th data-ng-click="doSort('city')">City</th>
                    <th data-ng-click="doSort('Money')">Money</th>
                </tr>
                <tr data-ng-repeat="person in customer | orderBy:sortBy:reverse | filter:nameText |filter:nameOnly |filter:cityOnly |filter:MoneyOnly">
                    <td> {{ person.name }} </td>
                    <td> {{ person.city}} </td>
                    <td> {{ person.Money}} </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

    </div>

    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.sortBy=  'name';
        $scope.reverse= false;

        $scope.customer= [{name:'Rasel',city:'Dhaka',Money:'10'},
                  {name:'Jon',city:'Khulna',Money:'20'},
                  {name:'Mr. Fox',city:'Rajshahi',Money:'30'},
                  {name:'Nabil',city:'Comilla',Money:'40'}];    

    });
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.